# identifier "va_list" is undefined in Code Composer Project

Tags: c++, variadic-functions, texas-instruments, code-composer

I am use TI 8.3.11 (Code Composer Studio) Device Family C6000, SYS/Bios 6.67.3.01

I have a problem with variadic function, which accepts a variable number of arguments. My class:

```
#include "stdint.h"
#include "stdarg.h"
#include <xdc/runtime/Error.h>
#include <xdc/runtime/System.h>
#include <xdc/runtime/Memory.h>
#include <ti/sysbios/heaps/HeapBuf.h>
#include "nexus.hpp"
class Neuron
{
public:
    explicit Neuron() = default;
    ~Neuron();
public:
    void AllocManyNexuses(int count, ...) noexcept;
}
```

And in cpp i determined it:

```
void Neuron::AllocManyNexuses(int count, ...) noexcept
{
    const xdc_runtime_IHeap_Handle nexusHandle=reinterpret_cast<xdc_runtime_IHeap_Handle>(heap4KbpNetNexus);
    Error_Block eb;
    Error_init(&eb);
    nexus =reinterpret_cast<Nexus*>(Memory_calloc(nexusHandle, sizeof(Nexus), 0, &eb));


    va_list doubleLists;
    va_start(doubleLists, count);    
    for(int i=0;i<count; ++i)
    {
    and etc
}
```

My compiler get me some dummy errors:

```
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/std.h", line 41: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 118: error #20: identifier "int_least8_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 119: error #20: identifier "uint_least8_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 120: error #20: identifier "int_least16_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 121: error #20: identifier "uint_least16_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 122: error #20: identifier "int_least32_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 123: error #20: identifier "uint_least32_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 126: error #20: identifier "int_least64_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 127: error #20: identifier "uint_least64_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 131: error #20: identifier "int_least40_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 132: error #20: identifier "uint_least40_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 147: error #20: identifier "uint8_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 150: error #20: identifier "uint16_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 153: error #20: identifier "uint32_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 156: error #20: identifier "uint64_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 162: error #20: identifier "intptr_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/bios_6_76_03_01/packages/ti/targets/std.h", line 163: error #20: identifier "uintptr_t" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/std.h", line 196: warning #552-D: variable "u" was set but never used
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 387: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 389: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 396: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 398: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 405: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 407: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 414: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 416: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 443: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
"C:/ti/ccs1220/xdctools_3_62_01_16_core/packages/xdc/runtime/System.h", line 445: error #20: identifier "va_list" is undefined
27 errors detected in the compilation of "../lib/containers/kbpVector.cpp".
gmake: *** [lib/containers/kbpVector.obj] Error 1
```

What I do wrong, guys?

Comment: Well it certainly should be `#include <stdint.h>` and `#include <stdarg.h>` but I'd be surprised if that explains this error.

Comment: I try to goolge and get some solutions like these, but do not help me

Comment: it should be `#include <cstdint>` and `#include <cstdarg>`, but afaik it doesnt actually matter

Comment: It seems to me that the problem is with the header files you are including. So I would remove all your code, and just include header files. See if you can work out which one is causing the problems. Of course header files should be written so that you can include whatever you need in whatever order, but it seems like that's not true of the header files you are using,

Comment: Error while including only, maybe these function is unavailable or have unclear way to include

Comment: What I've heard is that Texas Instruments isn't the best at implementing the standard i.e. not standard complete. Maybe these are some things that they don't support?

Comment: @Mestkon i know that templates and inline functions some time have some trobles. But i have no another device

Comment: Can you use [variadic template](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/parameter_pack) instead?

Comment: Avoid `va_list` in modern C++ if at all possible. Prefer type-safe variadic templates instead.

Comment: @Jarod42 will try and answer

Comment: I remember using `va_list` and `...` back in prehistoric times, when I was writing C, back when dinosaurs roamed the Earth. In current times, in C++, I use templates.

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <iostream>

template<class ...DOU>
static void product(DOU ...doubles) {
    constexpr int numOfArgs=sizeof...(doubles);
    double arr[numOfArgs]={};
    int index = 0;
    auto setValLamda=[&arr, &index](double i){
        arr[index]= i;
        ++index;
        return i;
    };
    auto supapro = { (setValLamda(doubles),...)};
    for (double val:arr)
    {
        std::cout << val << '\n';
    }
}



int main() {
    product<double>(2.2, 6.2);
    return 0;
}
```